# Does sequence contain 5 numbers that are each one apart solved recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012

This is the data:

```
create table #t
       (ID int)

insert into #t
values  
       (-2)
       ,(-1)
    -- ,(0)
       ,(1)
       ,(2)
       ,(3)
       ,(4)
       ,(7)
       ,(5)
       ,(21)
       ,(22)
       ,(23)
       ,(24)
       ,(25)
       ,(8);
```

We want to know if there are 5 numbers within the above sequence that are each 1 apart e.g. 21-22-23-24-25 gives a positive result. So is there an island of 5 anywhere in the list?

None recursively I've got a few possibilities but is there a simple recursive solution?
Or is there a simpler non-recursive solution?

```
--::::::::::::::
--:: 1. LONG-WINDED  
with t as
    (
    select  id,
        U = (id+5),
        L = (id-5)
    from    #t
    )
, up as
    (
    select  x.id,
        cnt = count(*)
    from    t x
        join t y on
        (y.id > x.L and y.id <= x.id)
    group by x.id
    )
, down as --<<MAYBE DOWN IS NOT NEEDED
    (
    select  x.id,
        cnt = count(*)
    from    t x
        join t y on
        (y.id < x.U and y.id >= x.id)
    group by x.id
    )
select id from up where cnt >= 5
union all
select id from down where cnt >= 5
```

Following two are better:

```
--::::::::::::::
--::
--:: 2. PRETTY!!
SELECT  *
FROM    #t A
WHERE   EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    #t B
    WHERE   (
         (A.id + 5) > B.id 
         AND
         A.id  <= B.id
        )
    HAVING  COUNT(*) >=5                
    )

--::::::::::::::
--::
--:: 3. PRETTY PRETTY!!
--::
SELECT ID
FROM   #t A
CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT  cnt = COUNT(*) 
    FROM    #t B 
    WHERE   (A.id + 5) > B.id AND A.id  <= B.id
    ) C
WHERE C.cnt>=5
```

Following used this reference to [Itzak article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/microsoft-sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-2)

```
--::::::::::::::
--::
--:: 4. One of the Windowed functions
--:: 
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT  ID,
        y = LAG(ID,4) OVER(ORDER BY ID),
        dif = ID - LAG(ID,4) OVER(ORDER BY ID)
    FROM    #t A
)
SELECT ID,y 
FROM   x
WHERE  dif = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a much simpler solution.  Take the difference between the numbers and an increasing sequence of numbers.  If the numbers are consecutive, the difference is constant.  So, you can do:

```
select grp, count(*) as num_in_sequence, min(id) as first_id, max(id) as last_id
from (select t.*,
             (id - row_number() over (order by id)) as grp
      from #t t
     ) t
group by grp
having count(*) >= 5;
```

EDIT:

I think this is the simplest of all.  One window function and a comparison:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(id, 4) over (order by id) as id4
      from #t
     ) t
where id4 - id = 4;
```

This *does* make the assumption that there are no duplicates in the `id`s, which is true of the OP data.

As I look further, this is the last solution in the OP.  Kudos!

Comment: +1 Really nice solution. Not sure if it is that "much simpler" than some of the solutions in OP.

Comment: @whytheq . . . I independently stumbled on the last solution.  I think that is the best solution if you assume no duplicates.

Comment: execution plans are very similar when comparing `ROW_NUMBER` solution to the `LAG/LEAD` solution. Not sure which is more efficient. Both these solutions are streets ahead of the others in OP because these two avoid Nested Loops. The `Row_Number` answer seems to have an extra `Sort` so guessing `LAG/LEAD` is the winner.

Comment: @whytheq . . . I would expect the `lead()` method to be best, because there is no aggregation.  But, they do different things.  That method tests for exactly 5 in a sequence (which is the question).  The `row_number()` method finds the size of all islands.